# How to assign value to an array of objects from main function

Tags: c++

```
class Vector{
public :
        int *v;
        Vector(int sz){
             v = new int[sz];
        }
        int & at(int idx){
             return v[i];
        }
```

};

```
int main(){
 Vector V(5);
 for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
     V.at(i) = i+1;
 }
 return 0;
```

}

In the above Program under main function inside the for loop I want to use V[i] instead of V.at(i) .

So what changes  should I make inside class Vector .Someone help.

I tried using constructor call , operator overloading etc , but failed every time getting a syntax error .

I am not a quite experienced person in OOP design .
So i expect help.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use STL vector.

Comment: `but failed every time getting a syntax error` Then show us what you tried and the error you get.

Answer (score 4):

Overload the `operator[]` function, like so:

```
int& operator[] (int idx) {
    return v[idx];
}
```

Additionally, you should supply a `const` version of your function which can be used when the `Vector` is const-qualified.

```
const int& operator[] (int idx) const {
    return v[idx];
}
```

Comment: Extra brownie points if you supply the `const` version and state why. Then, move to `std::size_t` rather than `int` for `idx`. Then delete the whole lot and use `std::vector`.

Comment: It is always good practise to check index out of range or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload [] operator.

```
int &operator[](int i)
      {
          if( i >= sz )
          {
              cout << "Index out of bounds" <<endl; 
              // return first element.
              return v[0];
          }
          return v[i];
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Note though that `if( i > SIZE )` should probably be `if( i >= SIZE )` (or even `if( i >= sz )` for consistency with the OP's code.)

Comment: Always a bad idea to silently cover up errors in a program. If you want bounds-checked access, throw an exception if the index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Every operator that you want to use with with your class needs to be overloaded.

You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) for details.

Off course unless this is homework the only sane thing to do is to use `std::vector`